# How can I find a good distracter for a key using python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

What I am trying to do is to create a Multiple Choice Question (MCQ) generation to our fill in the gap style question generator. I need to generate distracters (Wrong answers) from the Key (correct answer). The MCQ is generated from educational texts that users input. We're trying to tackle this through combining Contextual similarity, similarity of the sentences in which the keys and the distractors occur in and Difference in term frequencies Any help? I was thinking of using big data datasets to generate related distractors such as the ones provided by google vision, I have no clue how to achieve this in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is way too broad to be answered, though I would do my best to give you some pointers.

**If you have a closed set of potential distractors,** I would use word/phrase embedding to find the closest distractor to the right answer.

[Gensim's word2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) is a good starting point in python

**If you want your distractors to follow a template,** for example replace a certain word from the right answer with its opposite, I would use [nltk's wordnet](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) implementation to find antonyns / synonyms.